# Ambiguous reference advice

Tags: c#, scope

The following line of code

```
TreeView treeview = (TreeView)currentGroup.Content;
```

lists an error

> 'TreeView' is an ambiguous reference between '`System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`' and '`System.Windows.Controls.TreeView`'

I know the reason as I need to explicitly state which reference to use as both have `TreeView` eg :

```
System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeview = (System.Windows.Controls.TreeView)currentGroup.Content;
```

What is best practice for this? Is there another(neater) way of defining which reference `TreeView` must use if used extensively through several methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use particularly `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` for example, you just add

```
using TreeView = System.Windows.Forms.TreeView;
```

into your using statements list and within this class by default the compiler will be assuming `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` when you use `TreeView`.

Answer (score 4):

Use an alias in your `using` statement:

```
using WF = System.Windows.Forms;
using WC = System.Windows.Controls;
```

Then you can simply use:

```
WF::TreeView tv1;

WC::TreeView tv2;
```

The double colon forces the prefix to be treated as a namespace, so even you created a class called WF, the alias would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're casting, you can also save some typing by using the *var* keyword.

```
var treeview = (System.Windows.Controls.TreeView)currentGroup.Content;
```

Comment: I know this doesn't address your primary question (Maxim did that nicely), but you asked for 'neater' (which I interpret as 'tidier') code.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: `var treeview = currentGroup.Content;`

---

Solution if you can't use  `var`: In the top of your file change `using
System.Windows.Controls;` to `using cntrl = 
System.Windows.Controls;` this makes a alias, so this changes your original example to

```
cntrl.TreeView treeView;
treeView = (cntrl.TreeView)currentGroup.Content;
```

If `Content` must be cast you can combine the two to

```
var treeView = (cntrl.TreeView)currentGroup.Content;
```